# create new record in db

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Using asp.net mvc project I want to create a new ClientAccountAccess record.

```
private static void SetAccessCode(string guidCode)
        {
            using (EPOSEntities db = new EPOSEntities())
            {
                ClientAccountAccess client = new ClientAccountAccess();
                client.GUID = guidCode;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        //have also tried 
        //ClientAccountAccess client = new ClientAccountAccess()
        //{
        //    GUID = guidCode
        //};
        //db.SaveChanges();
```

Wont seem to save a new record?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add this record to context:

```
private static void SetAccessCode(string guidCode)
{
    using (EPOSEntities db = new EPOSEntities())
    {
        ClientAccountAccess client = new ClientAccountAccess();
        client.GUID = guidCode;

        // ClientAccountAccess is name of your DBSet in context. It might be different
        db.ClientAccountAccess.AddObject(client); 
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here is more samples of basic CRUD operations - http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=619